# Add to cart button alignment and sizing issues

Tags: html, css, paypal

I am having a hard time aligning my Paypal Add to cart button. I was able to modify the CSS/HTML on the button code Paypal provides to center-align one button, but the other buttons didn't work out. When I tried to center align them, the buttons' window/frame expanded to take up a lot of blank space on my page. How can I make this button center aligned and have a window/frame that's only as large as needed?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoqzQ.png)

Comment: Please provide a codepen or jsfiddle with the code!

Comment: I was able to get this answered by Paypal. It really was just about forcing the window frame hosting the button to contract

Answer (score 0):

you should put the code to here. By the way, you can follow this example.
**CSS**

```
.boxlink a:link, .boxlink a:visited{
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border: black solid 2px;
}

.boxlink a:hover, .boxlink a:active{
    background-color: #1a4891;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxlink">
    <a href="...">Learn more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to get this answered by Paypal. It really was just about forcing the window frame hosting the button to contract